# Traffic shaping with tc

Tags: networking, htb

I've been playing with tc and been reading a lot about shaping traffic. I've read that traffic can be shaped egress and policed ingress.
I have standard set up

LAN -->eth0[OPENWRT]-ppoawan---> INTERNET

I've managed to set up an outbound shaping without problems ,however what confuses me is limiting the bandwidth. Can we use HTB shaping on both ends (so that would make it egress for up and downloads ?) 
E.G

HTB on eth0 rate 1mbit and 512kbits on pppo-wan ?

Comment: Yes, create rules for each device.  eth0 rules for traffic being served to your users, and wan rules for upload limits.